# How to draw a map using mkmapview with driving directions between map annotations

Tags: mkmapview

I'm developing an App with some maps functionalities (among other things), I'd like to draw a map from my current location to a given destination, but I do not want to use the shareadapplication, The shared application does not have a BACK button for example and some other navigation items I already have.
I want to do it in my own viewcontroller with mkmapview on it. 
I already have the code to place the pin annotations, what I need is to trace the driving directions from A to B.

The other option is to use the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url] call to appear inside the viewcontroller window so I can keep my navigation items.

Any ideas?

thnxs

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the "other option". iOS apps do not run inside windows that you can put within your app, they are full screen apps and you can make you app switch to them, but you can't make other apps switch back to yours.

So, the big question is, where are you going to get driving directions from? Check out [GoogleMapsSDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start), OpenStreetMap and CloudMade, because iOS maps won't give you the directions.